# Javascript Class/Static Variables

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript from Head First Javascript (Morrison).

In one example, the author declares a variable 'signature' to be a class property of a class called Blog by doing the following:

```
    Blog.prototype.signature = "by Blogger-Name";
```

Is there difference between the above and declaring it like how I have below?

```
    Blog.signature = "by Blogger-Name";
```

Comment: @vinayakj It isn't because my question is not about whether a function is referenced or copied.

Comment: @vinayakj I did go through that post and did not see my answer. if you still think my question is answered there, please be more specific.

Comment: @vinayakj While you have answered my question, the post you referred me to does not. I'll just leave it at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All instances of `Blog` will have signature when you using `.prototype`. So when you instantiate `var blog = new Blog`. It will have a `signature property`.

If you were to just use `Blog.signature = x` Then when you create an object with `new` it wouldn't be there.

Comment: Yes, but all instances can access the signature property through Blog.signature anyway. So what is the point of declaring properties through .prototype then?

Comment: if you use both ways, then yes you can access it either way, but if you choose to use .prototype then you can think of it as a class member

Comment: True, but why would you declare any variable that remains the same value for all instances of a class as an instance variable? You would only declare it as a class/static variable... I should probably change my question at this point to: Is there a scenario where you would be required to declare a variable using .prototype?

Comment: I'd recommend asking a new question if you were planning on changing it.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a property of a `prototype` member of a constructor makes the property visible (when reading) from all instances.

This can be done to emulate `static` members of C++ classes and is often done in Javascript form methods (because methods are indeed just regular data members, differently from C++).

One example where this could be used instead for "data" is keeping all instances of a certain "class" in a container:

```
function Widget(x0, y0, x1, y1, name) {
    this.x0 = x0;
    this.y0 = y0;
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.name = name;
    this.all_instances.push(this);
}

Widget.prototype.all_instances = [];

var w1 = new Widget(10, 20, 30, 40, "First");
var w2 = new Widget(10, 20, 30, 40, "Second");
```

Note that however when writing to such a "static" property you're creating instead an instance property; `push` works because it's not writing to `.all_instances` but modifying its content (the array).